# Cannot check custom QComboBox options in Pyside6 Python

Tags: python, pyside6

I need to create a combo box with multiple selection(check boxes). I couldnt find any built-in widgets pyside6, so i have to create a custom combo box with multiple selection enabled. After referring to multiple articles, i finally implemented the combo box with multiple selection but the code was made for pyqt5 and i need to convert the code into pyside6. so i have changed the imports to pyside6 and the application is running. Even though combo box is created in my application, i was not able to select any of the options. Below I'm adding the code i tried.

**QCheckCombo.py**

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QEvent, QRect, QTimer

from PySide6.QtGui import (
    QPalette, QFontMetrics, QBrush, QColor, QPixmap, QGradient, QIcon
)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QComboBox, QAbstractItemView, QAbstractItemDelegate, QStyledItemDelegate,
    QApplication, QStyle, QStyleOption, QStyleOptionComboBox,
    QStyleOptionMenuItem, QStyleOptionViewItem, QStylePainter
)


class CheckComboBox(QComboBox):
    """
    A QComboBox allowing multiple item selection.
    """

    class ComboItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
        """
        Helper styled delegate (mostly based on existing private Qt's
        delegate used by the QComboBox). Used to style the popup like a
        list view (e.g windows style).
        """

        def isSeparator(self, index):
            return str(index.data(Qt.AccessibleDescriptionRole)) == "separator"

        def paint(self, painter, option, index):
            if option.widget is not None:
                style = option.widget.style()
            else:
                style = QApplication.style()

            option = QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
            option.showDecorationSelected = True

            # option.state &= ~QStyle.State_HasFocus & ~QStyle.State_MouseOver
            if self.isSeparator(index):
                opt = QStyleOption()
                opt.rect = QRect(option.rect)
                if isinstance(option.widget, QAbstractItemView):
                    opt.rect.setWidth(option.widget.viewport().width())
                style.drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_IndicatorToolBarSeparator,
                                    opt, painter, option.widget)
            else:
                super(CheckComboBox.ComboItemDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

    class ComboMenuDelegate(QAbstractItemDelegate):
        """
        Helper styled delegate (mostly based on existing private Qt's
        delegate used by the QComboBox). Used to style the popup like a
        menu. (e.g osx aqua style).
        """

        def isSeparator(self, index):
            return str(index.data(Qt.AccessibleDescriptionRole)) == "separator"

        def paint(self, painter, option, index):
            print('inside paint')
            menuopt = self._getMenuStyleOption(option, index)
            if option.widget is not None:
                style = option.widget.style()
            else:
                style = QApplication.style()
            style.drawControl(QStyle.CE_MenuItem, menuopt, painter,
                              option.widget)

        def sizeHint(self, option, index):
            menuopt = self._getMenuStyleOption(option, index)
            if option.widget is not None:
                style = option.widget.style()
            else:
                style = QApplication.style()
            return style.sizeFromContents(
                QStyle.CT_MenuItem, menuopt, menuopt.rect.size(),
                option.widget
            )

        def _getMenuStyleOption(self, option, index):
            print("inside menu style")
            menuoption = QStyleOptionMenuItem()
            palette = option.palette.resolve(QApplication.palette("QMenu"))
            foreground = index.data(Qt.ForegroundRole)
            if isinstance(foreground, (QBrush, QColor, QPixmap)):
                foreground = QBrush(foreground)
                palette.setBrush(QPalette.Text, foreground)
                palette.setBrush(QPalette.ButtonText, foreground)
                palette.setBrush(QPalette.WindowText, foreground)

            background = index.data(Qt.BackgroundRole)
            if isinstance(background, (QBrush, QColor, QPixmap)):
                background = QBrush(background)
                palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background, background)

            menuoption.palette = palette

            decoration = index.data(Qt.DecorationRole)
            if isinstance(decoration, QIcon):
                menuoption.icon = decoration

            if self.isSeparator(index):
                menuoption.menuItemType = QStyleOptionMenuItem.Separator
            else:
                menuoption.menuItemType = QStyleOptionMenuItem.Normal

            if index.flags() & Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable:
                menuoption.checkType = QStyleOptionMenuItem.NonExclusive
            else:
                menuoption.checkType = QStyleOptionMenuItem.NotCheckable

            check = index.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)
            menuoption.checked = check == Qt.Checked

            if option.widget is not None:
                menuoption.font = option.widget.font()
            else:
                menuoption.font = QApplication.font("QMenu")

            menuoption.maxIconWidth = option.decorationSize.width() + 4
            menuoption.rect = option.rect
            menuoption.menuRect = option.rect

            menuoption.menuHasCheckableItems = True
            menuoption.tabWidth = 0
            # TODO: self.displayText(QVariant, QLocale)
            # TODO: Why is this not a QStyledItemDelegate?
            display = index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
            if isinstance(display, str):
                menuoption.text = display
            else:
                menuoption.text = str(display)

            menuoption.fontMetrics = QFontMetrics(menuoption.font)
            state = option.state & (QStyle.State_MouseOver |
                                    QStyle.State_Selected |
                                    QStyle.State_Active)

            if index.flags() & Qt.ItemIsEnabled:
                state = state | QStyle.State_Enabled
                menuoption.palette.setCurrentColorGroup(QPalette.Active)
            else:
                state = state & ~QStyle.State_Enabled
                menuoption.palette.setCurrentColorGroup(QPalette.Disabled)

            if menuoption.checked:
                state = state | QStyle.State_On
            else:
                state = state | QStyle.State_Off

            menuoption.state = state
            return menuoption

    def __init__(self, parent=None, placeholderText="", separator=", ",
                 **kwargs):
        super(CheckComboBox, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)

        self.__popupIsShown = False
        self.__supressPopupHide = False
        self.__blockMouseReleaseTimer = QTimer(self, singleShot=True)
        self.__initialMousePos = None
        self.__separator = separator
        self.__placeholderText = placeholderText
        self.__updateItemDelegate()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """Reimplemented."""
        self.__popupIsShown = False
        super(CheckComboBox, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if self.__popupIsShown:
            self.__initialMousePos = self.mapToGlobal(event.position().toPoint())
            self.__blockMouseReleaseTimer.start(
                QApplication.doubleClickInterval())

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        """Reimplemented."""
        if event.type() == QEvent.StyleChange:
            self.__updateItemDelegate()
        super(CheckComboBox, self).changeEvent(event)

    def showPopup(self):
        """Reimplemented."""
        super(CheckComboBox, self).showPopup()
        self.__blockMouseReleaseTimer.start(
            QApplication.doubleClickInterval())
        view = self.view()
        view.installEventFilter(self)
        view.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.__popupIsShown = True

    def hidePopup(self):
        """Reimplemented."""
        self.view().removeEventFilter(self)
        self.view().viewport().removeEventFilter(self)
        self.__popupIsShown = False
        self.__initialMousePos = None
        super(CheckComboBox, self).hidePopup()
        self.view().clearFocus()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        """Reimplemented."""
        if self.__popupIsShown and \
                event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove and \
                self.view().isVisible() and self.__initialMousePos is not None:
            diff = obj.mapToGlobal(event.position().toPoint()) - self.__initialMousePos
            if diff.manhattanLength() > 9 and \
                    self.__blockMouseReleaseTimer.isActive():
                self.__blockMouseReleaseTimer.stop()
            # pass through

        if self.__popupIsShown and \
                event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease and \
                self.view().isVisible() and \
                self.view().rect().contains(event.position().toPoint()) and \
                self.view().currentIndex().isValid() and \
                self.view().currentIndex().flags() & Qt.ItemIsSelectable and \
                self.view().currentIndex().flags() & Qt.ItemIsEnabled and \
                self.view().currentIndex().flags() & Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable and \
                self.view().visualRect(self.view().currentIndex()).contains(event.position().toPoint()) and \
                not self.__blockMouseReleaseTimer.isActive():
            model = self.model()
            index = self.view().currentIndex()
            state = model.data(index, Qt.CheckStateRole) or Qt.Unchecked
            print(state)
            model.setData(index,
                          Qt.Checked if state == Qt.Unchecked else Qt.Unchecked,
                          Qt.CheckStateRole)
            self.view().update(index)
            self.repaint()
            return True

        if self.__popupIsShown and event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
                # toggle the current items check state
                model = self.model()
                index = self.view().currentIndex()
                flags = model.flags(index)
                state = model.data(index, Qt.CheckStateRole) or Qt.Unchecked
                if flags & Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable and \
                        flags & Qt.ItemIsTristate:
                    state = Qt.CheckState((int(state) + 1) % 3)
                elif flags & Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable:
                    state = Qt.Checked if state != Qt.Checked else Qt.Unchecked
                model.setData(index, state, Qt.CheckStateRole)
                return True
            # TODO: handle Qt.Key_Enter, Key_Return?

        return super(CheckComboBox, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        """Reimplemented."""
        painter = QStylePainter(self)
        option = QStyleOptionComboBox()
        self.initStyleOption(option)
        painter.drawComplexControl(QStyle.CC_ComboBox, option)
        # draw the icon and text
        checked = self.checkedIndices()
        if checked:
            items = [self.itemText(i) for i in checked]
            print(items)

            option.currentText = self.__separator.join(items)
            self.update()
        else:
            option.currentText = self.__placeholderText
            option.palette.setCurrentColorGroup(QPalette.Disabled)

        option.currentIcon = QIcon()
        painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ComboBoxLabel, option)

    def itemCheckState(self, index):
        """
        Return the check state for item at `index`
        Parameters
        ----------
        index : int
        Returns
        -------
        state : Qt.CheckState
        """
        state = self.itemData(index, role=Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if isinstance(state, int):
            return Qt.CheckState(state)
        else:
            return Qt.Unchecked

    def setItemCheckState(self, index, state):
        """
        Set the check state for item at `index` to `state`.
        Parameters
        ----------
        index : int
        state : Qt.CheckState
        """
        self.setItemData(index, state, Qt.CheckStateRole)

    def checkedIndices(self):
        """
        Return a list of indices of all checked items.
        Returns
        -------
        indices : List[int]
        """
        return [i for i in range(self.count())
                if self.itemCheckState(i) == Qt.Checked]

    def setPlaceholderText(self, text):
        """
        Set the placeholder text.
        This text is displayed on the checkbox when there are no checked
        items.
        Parameters
        ----------
        text : str
        """
        if self.__placeholderText != text:
            self.__placeholderText = text
            self.update()

    def placeholderText(self):
        """
        Return the placeholder text.
        Returns
        -------
        text : str
        """
        return self.__placeholderText

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        """Reimplemented."""
        event.ignore()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        """Reimplemented."""
        # Override the default QComboBox behavior
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Down and event.modifiers() & Qt.AltModifier:
            self.showPopup()
            return

        ignored = {Qt.Key_Up, Qt.Key_Down,
                   Qt.Key_PageDown, Qt.Key_PageUp,
                   Qt.Key_Home, Qt.Key_End}

        if event.key() in ignored:
            event.ignore()
            return

        super(CheckComboBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)

    def __updateItemDelegate(self):
        opt = QStyleOptionComboBox()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        if self.style().styleHint(QStyle.SH_ComboBox_Popup, opt, self):
            delegate = CheckComboBox.ComboMenuDelegate(self)
        else:
            delegate = CheckComboBox.ComboItemDelegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)


def example():
    app = QApplication(list(sys.argv))
    cb = CheckComboBox(placeholderText="None")
    model = cb.model()
    cb.addItem("First")
    model.item(0).setCheckable(True)
    cb.addItem("Second")
    model.item(1).setCheckable(True)
    cb.addItem("Third")
    model.item(2).setCheckable(True)
    cb.insertSeparator(3)
    cb.addItem("Fourth - Disabled")
    model.item(4).setEnabled(False)
    cb.show()
    cb.raise_()

    return app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(example())
```

It's showing ComboBox with checkable options but the options are not selectable.Where do I made the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are not considering that the default value of a checkable item is *not* `Unchecked`, but `None`.

Consider the following line:

```
state = Qt.Checked if state == Qt.Unchecked else Qt.Unchecked
```

If the previous `state` is `None`, the new value will always be `Qt.Unchecked`.

Logically, the solution is to do the opposite:

```
state = Qt.Unchecked if state == Qt.Checked else Qt.Checked
```

Another possibility:

```
state = model.data(index, Qt.CheckStateRole) or Qt.Unchecked
state = Qt.Checked if state == Qt.Unchecked else Qt.Unchecked
```

Or, even:

```
state = Qt.CheckState(0 if s == Qt.CheckState.Checked else 2)
```

Note that this last example is valid for both PySide6 and PyQt6, while the following will *only* work for PySide, since the truthfulness of an enum (as used in PyQt6) is considered valid even for a 0 value:

```
state = Qt.CheckState((not state) * 2)
```

---

That is not enough, though, as there are other issues with your implementation.

For instance, the popup timer is *never* started. That should be done immediately after the popup is shown (and before installing the filters):

```
    def showPopup(self):
        super(CheckComboBox, self).showPopup()
        self.__blockMouseReleaseTimer.start(
            QApplication.doubleClickInterval())
        # ...
```

Then, you are trying to manually call the `paintEvent()` and that's completely wrong for two reasons:

- you can *not* manually call `paintEvent()`, since only Qt can do that when it finds it necessary: you can only *schedule* a repaint using `update()` or eventually *force* an immediate repaint with `repaint()`;
- `paintEvent()` expects a `Paint` event type ([QPaintEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpaintevent.html), but the event in your code is a `MouseButtonRelease` type;

Comment: Thank you very much, I have fixed those paintEvent() call changing it to repaint(), also added the code to invoke popup timer immediately after the popup is shown. I have updated my question and made those changes in the code. But Im still not able to rectify the checkbox selection issue. You were correct, when i printed the 'state' value, it was showing '0' but when i changed it to 'state = model.data(index, Qt.CheckStateRole) or Qt.Unchecked', its printing the value as 'Unchecked'. But still, when i select an option, its neither checking the checkbox nor selecting the option.

Comment: It's possible that you still have things missing, as your code doesn't use many variables and objects (like you did for the timer). It seems that you found that code somewhere and now you're trying to adjust it to your needs, but only by blind trial and error, which may be fine, but it should also be done with *purpose*: if you try something and doesn't work, do some *reliable research* to understand why; for instance, instead of trying random things like `globalPosition()` "guessing" what they do, [read the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmouseevent.html). The same goes for the rest.

Comment: I don't know why you're not able to select items, as in my tests worked perfectly fixing the above. Try to add some print here and there to understand what is going on, ensure that events are properly propagated and do research the functions that you're using. That piece of code is *not* an easy one: if you don't even know the basics of Qt events, you cannot hope to fix it.

Comment: Actually im very new to QT and i found this code online which was created for PyQt5. And  i altered it to minimalize the code for sharing here, and the altered code was working fine on pyqt5. I tried to find the documentation about the globalPosition() and i was unable to find it.Thanks to you for sharing the documation and  i have fixed it.

Comment: I tried to print the 'state' and it is working fine too, like it keeps changing the state between checked and unchecked but the value was not updating on the UI

Comment: i found out that checkbox selection was made inside the 'paint()' in 'ComboMenuDelegate' class. i tried printing inside that paint() and it seems its not invoking that method. (I have updated the full code in the question)

Comment: Sorry but I've already provided an answer that addresses the main problem. With all due respect, this is not a debugging service or a code help desk: as said, the code you're using is quite advanced, if you want to use it, you ***must*** understand it. It requires months, if not *years* of patient study and experience in order to fully understand the underlying aspects of Qt widgets, painting, styling and event handling. It may require much less to *fix* existing code, but the fact remains: you have to do the biggest part, *research*. Take your time, go to the documentation, and study it.

Comment: I understand and thanks for all your help. I have gone through the documentation and i understood the purpose of each methods and events used here. Also, I have tried to implements things with that knowledge but couldn't fix those issues. As a one last favour, could you please point out where the issue is at? I will do my own research on that and if i get it right, i will update that here. Thank you!

Comment: As already told, the code I provided addresses the problem: I am perfectly able to click on an item and select it, so you might have issues specific to your OS. Also, `ItemIsTristate` is obsolete since Qt5, and it should be `ItemIsUserTristate`. Ensure that you run your program in a terminal or prompt, *not* just the IDE, as many IDEs are not always capable of capturing all errors (especially if they are silent and don't cause fatal exceptions).